# how to use onDelete: 'CASCADE' on TypeORM

Tags: typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I have 2 migrations Users and Posts and Posts has a `onDelete: 'CASCADE'`. For some reason when I delete a User with a Posts it throws an error saying:

```
"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`development_db`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))",
```

but I already set my Posts entity to `onDelete: 'CASCADE'`. What trips me off is when I add `ON DELETE CASCADE` on my posts migration the cascade delete works even though I removed `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` on my posts model. Any idea? so what's the use of `onDelete` in typeorm when you can set it on migration and not on the entity but still works.

USER Migration:

```js
/* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class UsersTable1575433829516 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.query(`
            CREATE TABLE users (
              id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
              username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
              email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
              password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
              createdAt DATETIME NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
        `);
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.dropTable('users', true);
  }
}
```

POST Migration:

```js
/* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class PostsTable1581617587575 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.query(`
        CREATE TABLE posts (
          id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
          title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          body TEXT(65000) NOT NULL,
          createdAt DATETIME NOT NULL,
          updatedAt DATETIME,
          PRIMARY KEY(id),
          userId INT NOT NULL,
          FOREIGN KEY (userId) 
                  REFERENCES users (id)
        );
    `);
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.dropTable('posts', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have to add cascade also in your migrations :)

Comment: @Loki That's what I did. I just thought that It works like in rails. you can just set it through the model. thanks

Comment: You have to add it to model & then use generate function of typeORM cli to generate migrations, but sometimes it wont add cascade

Comment: I also did that the generated migrations are incorrect. so I have a Post entity and try to generate migration like `typeorm migration:generate -n migrationPostsTable` and it uses the User Entity. So I have to manually create the migration myself.

Answer (score 10):

I was running into this same error message (`"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"`) because I had put the `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` in the `@OneToMany` decorator, instead of the `@ManyToOne` decorator, where it needed to be in order to generate the migration correctly.

Here's what didn't work for me:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {

    //...

    @OneToMany(() => Post, (post) => post.user, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    public posts: Post[];

    //...

}
```

Here's what worked for me:

```js
@Entity()
export class Post {

    // ...

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.posts, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    public user: User;

    // ...

}
```

I'm guessing this is the issue, because based on one of your comments, it sounds like you're coming from the Rails world. In Rails, you specify the 'cascade delete' on the 'One' side (`has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy`). In contrast, TypeORM seems to need it on the 'Many' side.

Comment: i forgot about this and made it manual delete by code not by sql. thank you. ill this and comeback you to.

Comment: I had the same problem and adding the {onDelete: 'CSCADE'} on the @MenyToOne end did the trick. I have no idea what is the logic behind it though. Also check your migrations auto-generated files and make sure you have 'ON DELETE CASCADE'.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your migration the property ON DELETE, like this !

```
/* eslint-disable class-methods-use-this */
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class PostsTable1581617587575 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.query(`
        CREATE TABLE posts (
          id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
          title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          body TEXT(65000) NOT NULL,
          createdAt DATETIME NOT NULL,
          updatedAt DATETIME,
          PRIMARY KEY(id),
          userId INT NOT NULL,
          FOREIGN KEY (userId) 
                  REFERENCES users (id)
                  ON DELETE CASCADE
        );
    `);
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {
    await queryRunner.dropTable('posts', true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).